# ActiveRecord leaks connections when using in Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, connection-pooling, rack

For a very database intensive view, I've turned to database denormalization/caching to reduce server resource demand and increase performance for users. The view is a summary view composed of data from many different tables, so a lot of different data changes also update the cache.

To reduce the churn in the cache, I turned to Rack middleware. My middleware looks like this:

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    # ... prepare in memory storage for what needs to change
    return_value = @app.call(env)
    # ... commit changes to the database
    return_value
  end
end
```

Everything looked great until the app was put under load for a while. Then I started seeing the following error occassionally in the logs:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds.  The max pool size is currently 5; consider increasing it.
```

When I remove the middleware, the application works normally again.

How do I fix the connection leak when using ActiveRecord from Rack middleware?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides a method for clearing connections manually - `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!`. Update the `call` method in the middleware to clear the active connections after the changes are made in the database.

```
def call(env)
  # ... prepare in memory storage for what needs to change
  return_value = @app.call(env)
  # ... commit changes to the database
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! # fixes the connection leak
  return_value
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html